# can i unplug my Arduino project when i'm done installing the libraries and it still work the way it did when it is plugged in

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

can i unplug my Arduino project when i'm done installing the libraries and it still work the way it did when it is plugged in

Comment: Unplug it from what? Your question is a bit vague. Do you mean unplug the USB cable from your PC? It won't "still work" unless you plug in a different power source.

Comment: like what type of of power source can use. i apologize for not being clear enough but i am new at this and don't even know where to start. i don't even have my equipment yet.  but thank you for being able to answer my question.

Comment: As st2000 said, the program resides in program memory (firmware if you like) and stays there until replaced, even with the power off. Whether it works "the same way" depends a bit on other factors (eg. do you use the USB for sending messages?) but in principle it should still work.

Answer (score 2):

Once you compile and upload your arduino sketch and any libraries it uses, your code is stored in nonvolatile memory inside the processor. You can unplug your arduino and power it up later and it will run your code again with out any help from your computer.